# Nest one label under another without losing filters

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have 2 existing labels in my Gmail account.

I would like to make one of them a child label of another.

I have a set of complicated filters attached to the would-be child label, so I don't want to just delete it and create a new one with the same name as a child of the would-be parent.

Is there anyway I can move the existing label to make it a child?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply rename your label to be in the parent/child form.

For example, if your labels are currently:

- Parent
- Child

Just rename `Child` to `Parent/Child`. All the filters will automatically be updated.

Comment: Follow up from @senseful's answer, I believe you'll need to enable this feature in the Gmail Labs (little green beaker at the top right of GMail).